# Could you please help getting started in predictive modelling a large dataset in R?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

I am fairly new to machine learning, I am understanding the basics of regression analysis currently. I have come across this dataset California Housing https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing provided by UCI. Is there any place that walks through for above dataset ( or any large dataset in general ) how to break down a unknown dataset and build a regression model out of it?

This will really help me in giving a high level picture and then i can work on details.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at "An Introduction to Statistical Learning" by Hastie and Tibshirani. The ebook is for free (http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) and they provide a good video tutorial as well. They also work with the Boston housing dataset.
Furthermore, all examples are done with R and are easily reproducible (code is available).